# Python - Use flask to get args string with ampersand

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, api, flask

I have a GET endpoint, this endpoint takes several URL parameter as an input. One of these being Company Name. This work fine, until I try to send a string with an ampersand:

> Rock & Bolt

Postman correctly encodes this to %26 so my URL looks like `?companyname=Rock %26 Bolt`.

However, when I receive it in my endpoint like this: `c_name = args.get('companyname, None)`, what I get is `'Rock '`.

How can I adjust this so that I can send in an ampersand in my URL parameters?

Comment: & is special character that is used to separate the key value pairs. Avoid ampersand.

Comment: @Debendra But I cant tell all companies with an "&" in their name to change name ^^ These are real world companies that I want to be able to search for